# Calling a statically-linked static method in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, static-methods, static-linking

I'm trying to call a statically-linked static method of a C++ class, but I'm getting the VS linker error LNK2019, "unresolved external symbol". Here's the library source:

```
// in header file
#define DllExport __declspec (dllexport)
class MyClass{
public:
    DllExport
    static HWND WINAPI myFunc();
};
// in cpp file
DllExport
HWND WINAPI MyClass::myFunc(){ /* create a GUI window that has instance of MyClass set as its property (using ::SetProp) */ }
```

myFunc is to serve as an entry point for creating objects of MyClass, which resides hidden in the library. Only such static functions can be used to influence the functionality of a MyClass instance (by providing the corresponding HWND).
Here's the library consumer:

```
#define DllImport __declspec(dllimport)
DllImport
HWND WINAPI myFunc();
...
int main(){
    HWND hWnd=myFunc();
    ... // work with the window and attached MyClass instance
}
```

(I believe) all file linkages are set correctly - originally, myFunc was designed as a standalone function and all worked just fine. I suspect it must be some calling convetion mismatch that makes the linker produce the error on myFunc.
Read through multiple articles on this topic, namely

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL

and

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx

but they didn't solve my problem.

Thanks for a suggestion!

Comment: Your static method is dynamically-linked. Your export side is fine, so the project using the DLL is the culprit. Make sure to include the whole class definition and a corresponding __declspec(dllimport). It's easier if you use like an `API` macro which is configured for export when a preprocessor directive (ex: `BUILDING_LIB`) is defined and import otherwise so that you can just include the same header in both projects.

Comment: Also make sure to link against the stub lib, though I'm assuming you do that already since you got the standalone function working properly without looking up symbols manually.

Comment: Well, I'm quite sure I'm linking statically (producing LIB instead of DLL). But what puzzles me is having to include the whole MyClass definition even if no other but static functions are public in MyClass (I take it static functions virtually are classical C++ functions). From my perspective, the body of the function "knows" what to do (no matter if the compiled instructions emerged from a procedural or object-oriented code), so I'm missing at this moment a reason to include the whole class declaration.

Comment: Btw, just tried your suggestion, ending up with IntelliSense complaining that "incomplete type is not allowed", referring to my attempt to invoke MyClass::myFunc() in the consument app.

Comment: Gee, now I can see the confusion - I named this thread "dynamically-linked". Please, the function is really to be linked STATICALLY ! (Don't know what I was thinking of when writing it ! )

Comment: If you want to link it statically, no need to bother with DLL export. Just include the source code in every project or link against it as a static library. There should be no mention of DLL stuff for static linkage.

Comment: But that's my bad -- I edited your post since I really thought your goal was to create a DLL module. If you just want a static library, you can forget the dllexport/dllimport specifiers and just write code as you normally would. To use it in more than one project, make sure to specify your project a static library which will output a `.lib` file, and to link against it (linker properties) in the additional projects that use the static library.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, linking against it statically by having the LIB included. But despite that, the linker can't find the entry point of the function. Here's the problem put in code (unzip to D:\StaticLink or change the include directive in the consumer app), 
http://nestorovic.hyperlink.cz/staticlink.zip

Comment: Do you actually want to create a DLL or no? With a DLL, you can distribute a separate binary that shares the same code among those that use it. Now that can still involve statically linking against what's called a 'stub'. That contains all the function declarations and symbols to dynamically link against, but technically it's still dynamic linking. If you do want to do this, two things you need to change: 1: you got this use of `MYAPP` backwards. You want the library to export the symbol and the application using it to import it, but you have it the other way around...

Comment: 2. Your project is configured as a static library when it's trying to use dynamic linkage for the static method. So you want to reconfigure that project to be a DLL if you do that.

Comment: Now if you don't want to actually create a DLL and just want static linking, then what you want to do is just take out the dllexport/dllimport and `DllApi` stuff outright.

Comment: At this moment, I want to link statically. I read somewhere that I can selectively choose which symbols to make "visible" in the library, so since then I've been sticking to the import/export things (no matter if that information is true or not...). I admit the MYAPP switch is used in a bit confusing way - the first line reads "if not defined MYAPP" :-) Also, could you a bit elaborate the second point with the reconfiguration of the project? I still do want to stick to the statical linking, so what changes am I supposed to make? :-)

Comment: Oh my bad, then your export/import specifiers are okay -- for a DLL you just want to make sure to actually build that `lib` project as a DLL. If you aren't going the DLL route and want to just keep it as a static lib, then you don't need to decorate the static method at all. Just remove anything mentioning `dll` when declaring such functions and you should be fine. With a static lib, there's no idea of exporting symbols like you have with a DLL, so everything is visible (like a white box, whereas the DLL is a black box that has to selectively export symbols and make them visible).

Comment: So for the static lib route, just take out the `DllApi` macro and its usage. Other than that, all you need to do is make sure `app` links against `lib.lib` which you appear to be doing just fine. The linker was getting confused since you were declaring the function like it's going to be exported through a DLL but with no DLL actually involved.

Comment: My apologizes but still no results. Did exactly what you suggested and still getting the IntelliSense "incomplete type is not allowed" error, even for a normal function (not a static class member) that I've just added (and updated the online project). Still doing something terribly wrong. :-(

Comment: Let me try a formal answer since it's a bit difficult to illustrate in comments.

Comment: Added a formal answer.

Comment: GOT IT ! :-)
The problem was in me not having included Windows.h when compiling the consumer (hence WINAPI macro being not defined, hence compiler complaining with C4430 "missing type specifier - int assumed" once encountering the line "void WINAPI myNormalFunc();" in Lib.h). Ike, thank you so much for the time, effort, and information on libraries, I very much appreciate it! :-)

Comment: Ike, thank you for the formal answer, you were nine seconds quicker :-) About to mark it as solving my problem. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your goal is to create static library, the first thing we want to do is eliminate any mention of `dllexport/dllimport`. Such specifiers are only used when you actually create a DLL project.

So for `lib.h`, we only need this (with some include guards added for good measure):

```
// lib.h
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

class MyClass{
public:
    static void myFunc();
};

#endif
```

The `WINAPI` specification is also unnecessary since you're the one calling the method and can just use the default calling convention without ABI issues (though if you do want to use `WINAPI` anyway, then you need to include `<windows.h>` in your header file).

For `lib.cpp`, we only need this:

```
// lib.cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include "lib.h"

void MyClass::myFunc(){
    ::MessageBox(0,"myFunc call!",NULL,0);
}
```

For `main.cpp` in your `app` project, we only need this:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <D:\staticlink\lib\lib.h>

int main(){
    std::cout << "ahoj";
    MyClass::myFunc();
    char buf[10];
    std::cin >> buf;
    return 0;
}
```

I'd recommend configuring your include paths to find `lib.h` through your project settings instead of using absolute paths in your source code, but perhaps you can do that later after you get everything working.

After that, if a problem remains, the only thing you should need to ensure is that your `app` project is linking against `lib.lib` properly (linker settings).

Comment: Ike, thank you for the formal answer, you were nine seconds quicker :-) About to mark it as solving my problem. :-) In this respect, thank you so much for the time, effort, and information on libraries, I very much appreciate it!

Comment: NP -- sorry for editing your post to specify dynamic linkage. I was extremely confused (as with the linker) about using dllexport for a static library, so I thought your actual goal was to create a DLL. With a static lib, no need for that kind of stuff.

Comment: Definitely not a problem - would change the post title myself but don't know how.

Comment: It might be worth noting that if you ever do want to create a DLL, you were very close to the right answer -- just needed to configure that `lib` project to output a DLL. So if you ever want a DLL next time, you should know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your import header file should look more like:

```
#define DllApi __declspec (dllexport)
class MyClass{
public:
    DllApi
    static HWND WINAPI myFunc();
};
```

Comment: Including the whole class definition doesn't work - IntelliSense complains that "incomplete type is not allowed", referring to my attempt to invoke MyClass::myFunc() in the consument app. (Unless I'm missing some point.)

Comment: Gee, now I can see the confusion - I named this thread "dynamically-linked". Please, the function is really to be linked STATICALLY ! (Don't know what I was thinking of when writing it ! )